# Is it possible to add images to comments?

Tags: support, comments, images

I was wondering if it is possible to post a comment with an image.

Recently, during a question about data-visualization in Cross Validated, there was a controversy about using one type of chart for another.

I had posted a question about pie-charts, after reading some references I decided to build an example and clarify the point of using waffle-chart vs pie-chart. In a way, my example was not an answer it was more properly a comment on waffle-charts. But it seems to be impossible to post a comment with an image (Maybe, there is a way but I can't figure out how).

I don't know if it is relevant to post images in comments in other SO sites. So, if there is no way to post images in comments... why not making it possible? And if there is a way to post an image with a comment, how I can do it?

Comment: Well, you can just use http://imgur.com and upload the images manually then post a link to it in the comments, or if you find the discussion dragging out too long use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) instead. Otherwise, no, its not possible

Comment: I'd rather use the Markdown editor to automatically upload images [to the SE-provided Pro account](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), @Yi, and then copy the imgur.com URL into the comment. That ensures the image won't be deleted after some time.

Comment: @Yi Jiang and @Arjan, thanks for your comments. I found them very useful! That seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a `support` question not a `feature-request`.

Answer (score 23):

You can't (see [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)). The only formatting allowed in comments is things that change a single line (**bold**, `code`, etc.). Things that take up multiple lines aren't available, because comments don't span blocks like posts do. Along the same thinking, comments have a fairly low character limit. All of this serves to keep comments compact; adding images lets you make huge comments, and posts can have dozens or hundreds of comments:

[image: Screenshot of the horror]

If you really need an image, just [link to it in the comment](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_nm9ySucveA8/TEYgGF9iEWI/AAAAAAAAAOo/uC62nczWcEk/s1600/unicorn1.jpg) and people can click through

Comment: Also, images would allow for HUGE text!

Comment: +1 for hypothetically showing the images in comments ;)

Comment: But who would put unicorns in the comments?? who would do something like that?

Comment: **Feature request right now**

Comment: @Pekka Granted. Only for unicorns.

Comment: @Arjan http://i.imgur.com/X35E6.png

Comment: @jjnguy http://so.mrozekma.com/jeff/All%20my%20comments%20would%20be%20in%20this%20form

Comment: @Michael, haha.  Great pic.

Comment: I thought that Stackexchange discourages the use of links to externally saved files?

Comment: @Karlo not in comments

Comment: @ShadowWizard They were probably referring to the image that was hosted on my domain up until a half hour ago

Comment: @MichaelMrozek oh, in the answer itself? I see. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: You are right, big images would just be very obtrusive in comments. When the images become very small, they're just going to have symbolic meaning , so emojis work fine for that

Answer (score 20):

A work around is to start a new answer or question, use the image upload button to get the images into the stakcoverflow imgur account, then take the links and link to the images from your comments.  Discard the answer or question you started.

Comment: That CAN'T be allowed!  But I love it. Can you show me a link to where you've done this or seen this done?

Comment: I think that's exactly what was done under my answer, by Fibbles, right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281191/how-do-i-view-a-function-list-from-my-open-file-or-project-in-codeblocks. It worked great, so I think it absolutely *should* be allowed. Him doing that was very helpful for me, and then I went ahead and added his image into my answer.

Comment: 8 years on. Edit the question, copy the imgur link, exity the edit with no changes, use the link.

Comment: It certainly works if you actually let the answer post, then delete it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071004/visual-studio-2019-search-history-not-in-table/61071029#comment108043527_61071029 It didn't actually occur to me to take the links while editing and then discard. TIL!

Comment: better to use imgur.com IMHO why overload S.E. ?

Comment: February 2021: just did this for my comment to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151711/python-yfinance-axis-formatting-issue), by pasting the picture in the answer box to get the link. Posted the comment, refreshed the page just to check, works perfectly!