# Should images be allowed in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I came across a question which was from a new user and I was not sure about the exact solution but had an image that could have been useful in that scenario.

And as I was not sure it could be the answer so it would have been a good option to attach the image in comment but could not find it in the help for comments.

Comment: Can't you just post the barelink in the comment?

Comment: I have the image on local machine and not hosted somewhere.

Comment: You will need to host the image somewhere so it can be viewed

Comment: I see 2 questions above. That doesn't work well. Both are duplicates: [Is it possible to add images to comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments) and [How can I upload an image to use it in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145994/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-use-it-in-a-comment)

Answer (score 2):

No, comments do not support images.

You can only *link* to an image. You can even use a blank post window to upload that image to the Stack Exchange imgur.com service (just use the image button, copy the URL, don't actually submit the post).

Comment: Ohh is it? That's great. Will try that out. Thanks. Nice trick/

Comment: Will the image link not become invalidated if it is not attached in any post? How does that work?

Comment: @NarendraPathai: There is no validation of image links as far as I know.

Comment: So once I upload an image on Stack Exchange service it remains there forever?

Comment: Define "forever" haha. Probably as long as imgur exists.

Comment: It remains there as long as there is an agreement between Stack Exchange and Imgur, yes. It may even mean that if ever that agreement ended, that Stack Exchange would migrate all those images elsewhere and fix all the links.